# Email validation in asp net web form

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

Just curious to know, I am using TextMode="Email" in asp net web form which works as expected however when we provide "info" as a part of first word(Before @) like "info@xyz.com" or "jyo.info@xyz.com" or "jyoinfo@xyz.com" then It says invalid email. I believe it is because the first word(Before @) contains "info"(all small) but making any single or all character of "info" in capital letter work fine. Anyone please explain the reason for this behavior and if i am somewhere wrong then please guide me in right direction.

Comment: Probably should close this question as we were intensely restricting these kind of format like "info@" etc. Other then that our regex is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your own regular expression to make the email test non-case sensitive. Below is a pretty decent regex for email testing (not too aggressive).

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$
```